Are expected numbers of visits to a point for a random walk in $\mathbb Z^d$ explicitly known?
Let $\lbrace Z_n\rbrace$ be the standard random walk in $\mathbb Z^d$ starting at $0$ (i.e. $Z_0=0$ a.s.). Is there an explicit formula to compute the expected amount of visits to a certain point $(x,y,z)$? I am specially interested in the case of $\mathbb Z^3$, i.e., I'm looking for a formula for
$\mathbb E(|\lbrace n: Z_N=(x,y,z)\rbrace ||Z_0=(0,0,0))$. I have tried to simulate some of these values numerically (for $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ it seems like the expected number of visits is 1.5). Of course, in dimensions $1$ and $2$ this value is infinite for any point, as the random walk is positive and recurrent.
